# Adding a UIAlertView onto a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a scrollView that is 900 high. At the bottom I have a button that does some network work.

When it's complete I call a `UIAlertView` to appear to tell the user if there was success or failure in the action.

The alert appears (I think) but it's not visible as it is somewhere on the middle of the scrollview and the view is now locked.

How can I set my alert to appear near the bottom of the scrollview, like at y position 700?

My code for UIAlertView

```
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Alert"
                             message: @"Success"
                            delegate: self
                   cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                   otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease] show];
```

Comment: What happens if you move the show and the autorelease into separate statements?

Comment: Your `autorelease` is causing the problem for you. Try seperating this into three statements.

Comment: The `autorelease` would not be the problem, it correctly balances the `alloc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIAlertView` is always attached to key window, not to the top view. So it's not appearing at all. You should check your display code.

Comment: Why does the screen lock so? And is there a work around to get this working?

Comment: Your screen "locks" because you're doing something that is blocking the main thread (like sending synchronous request to the server). Use `NSURLConnection` with delegate methods to keep the ui responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're showing the alert view from your main thread ?

Answer (score 0):

I Think its not possible with adding subview scrollview .but we can set any place alert view accordly set frame before its present

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView; 
{
alertView..frame=CGRectMake(10, 4, 149, 900);
}
```